# Expression in ng-init not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

So I am trying to have many divs with background images and disable the background image when I hover over any particular div.

```
<div id="interest" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="interest in vm.interestList"
     ng-init="myStyle={'background-image': 'url(interest.src)'}"
     ng-style="myStyle" ng-mouseenter="myStyle={}"
     ng-mouseleave="myStyle={'background-image': 'url(interest.src)'}">
    <button id="interestButton" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" >{{interest.interestName}}</button>
</div>
```

For some reason the myStyle in ng-init never gets the actual value in interest.src rather just gets 'interest.src'. I also tried {{interest.src}} but that does not work.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not sure this is what ng-init is for, but anyways you can lose that and the mouse enter/leave and just set the style to include the background image, then use CSS :hover to remove the background image while the element is being hovered over. the style isn't working because interest.src is within a string value for background-image, it's just a string that isn't bound to the variable.

Comment: I tried the :hover approach but the css property was not able to override the ng-style and the background image remained. So i thought maybe the ng-style has a higher priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.interestList = [{interestName:"One", src:"img/one.png"}];
  $scope.url = function(url){
    return 'url('+url+')';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

  <div id="interest" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="interest in interestList"
     ng-init="myStyle = {'background-image': url(interest.src)}"
     ng-style="myStyle" ng-mouseenter="myStyle={}"
     ng-mouseleave="myStyle={'background-image': url(interest.src)}">
    <button id="interestButton" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" >{{interest.interestName}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<div id="interest" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="interest in vm.interestList"
   ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+interest.src+')'}" ng-mouseenter="{}"
   ng-mouseleave="{'background-image': 'url('+interest.src+')'}">
  <button id="interestButton" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" >{{interest.interestName}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to interpolate the string literal of your evaluated angular expressions for `interest.src`

Instead of 
`ng-init="myStyle={'background-image': 'url(interest.src)'}"` change it to `ng-init="myStyle={'background-image': 'url(' + interest.src + ')'}"`

Note the string concantenation via `+`

Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DeDDfGOb9ULcbLrriS4K?p=preview)